# sklearn RFECV with missing value

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I slightly modify the tutorial from [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py)

So that X has a missing value.  This doesn't work with the original svc, so I try to create a `clf` as a pipeline-- an imputer and then an svc.  However, I still get a missing value error. How does one impute when chaining a feature selection method like RFECV with a classifier in a pipeline?

```
print(__doc__)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

# Build a classification task using 3 informative features
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=20, n_features=25, n_informative=3,
                           n_redundant=2, n_repeated=0, n_classes=8,
                           n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=0)

X[1][8]=np.NAN#plant missing value

# Create the RFE object and compute a cross-validated score.
svc = SVC(kernel="linear")
clf=make_pipeline(Imputer(),svc)
# The "accuracy" scoring is proportional to the number of correct
# classifications
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=clf, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(2),
              scoring='accuracy')
rfecv.fit(X, y)

print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)

# Plot number of features VS. cross-validation scores
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Cross validation score (nb of correct classifications)")
plt.plot(range(1, len(rfecv.grid_scores_) + 1), rfecv.grid_scores_)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with what you are trying to do here:

1. RFECV performs a check on X at the start if its fit function, by
   calling `check_X_y(X, y, "csr")`. This causes the `ValueError` you
   are seeing, since X doesn't even reach the Imputer.
2. Even if this wasn't the case, it appears you cannot use a Pipeline
   in RFECV, since this classifier does not expose "coef_" or
   "feature_importances_" attributes, which is a prerequisite for using
   RFECV.

What I suggest is using the Imputer on the entirety of X, even though this might cause an indirect leak between your train and test data. You can then run RFECV directly on the SVC classifier.

```
X = Imputer().fit_transform(X)
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=svc, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(2),
              scoring='accuracy')
rfecv.fit(X, y)
```